# Java annotation processing: Accessing "Element"s of non-annotated classes possible?

Tags: java, annotations, javac, annotation-processing

Java annotation processing (since Java 6) is a very good concept, because it allows to access lots of information about classes and methods through the `Element` interface (and others).

But sadly, I had to find out empirically, that non-annotated classes are never passed to a custom annotation processor:

```
warning: No SupportedAnnotationTypes annotation found on
    my.TESTProcessor, returning an empty set.
```

Are my findings true? Or can I "trick" the compiler to give my custom annotation processor information about **non-annotated** classes as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great!

This gives me really **all** classes, not just annotated ones:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
```

The spec of that anotation says:

```
[...] Finally, "*" by itself represents the set of all annotation types,
including the empty set. Note that a processor should not claim "*"
unless it is actually processing all files [...]
```

Tested, **works**!